# Using git without history

Tags: git, directory, synchronization

So we want to have some sort of directory syncing without using the history of git.

So we want to be able to add a file to the repository, commit it. But also be able to delete it from the repo, so it won't take any more space. Just look at it as some sort of directory sync tool.

Whatever we try, it just doesn't seem to work. With the filter-tree option we don't get the results we want because the file seems to stay in the repository.

Isn't there some sort of init option to enable the repository just to keep the HEAD revision and work that way?

So my question:

Is there a way to use git, without history?

Thanks

Comment: Git without history? Isn't that DropBox? 
Why are you worried about disk space? Unless you're storing huge video files, this should be moot.

Comment: Yeah we like to have some sort of dropbox implementation. The reason we chose git is because there are libraries for mobile devices so we don't need to write an update service ourselves. If anybody knows an alternative be free, but it needs to run on android and ios.

Comment: @user3115705 If all you worry about is local history, use svn or cvs or something, they don't clone the repository. I've used subversion as a delivery system before, there are libraries available as well, so you can integrate it directly if you want.

Comment: @roe thanks for your reply, I think im going to do it like that. I thought about subversion before and was trying it the git way because our systems use git. I see it's not easy, and not meant the way I want to use it and will start prototyping the svn way. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like git-annex may be what you're looking for.

http://git-annex.branchable.com/